Naming an ether attached to an iso alkene
I am struggling with naming the compound below from a research paper I've been studying:

Could you please confirm if the following naming is correct for this molecule?
(3-methyl buten-2-yl) 2-phenyl ethyl ether
If not, your suggestions are welcome.
Cheers!

There are various problems with your name. First of all, for ethers, substitutive names (i.e. {2-[(3-methylbut-1-en-2-yl)oxy]ethyl}benzene) are preferred – and not functional class names (like 3-methylbut-1-en-2-yl 2-phenylethyl ether).
